# Two almost identitcal fragments but only one updates

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a tabbed activity with three fragments. Fragment 1 adds information to Firestore and fragments two and three pull information for now.

After I add the data using fragment one, only the spinner in fragment three updates, fragment two's spinner does not update.

They have identical code to load the spinners so I don't understand why fragment two does not reload the spinner the way fragment three does. Could someone help identify why it does not behave the same as fragment three?

Fragment 2 code(the one that does not update):

```
public class AddFacultyFragment extends Fragment {
@BindView(R.id.spinner_search_UniFac)
Spinner spinner_search_UniFac;
ArrayList<University> listUni = new ArrayList<>();
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_faculty,
            container,
            false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    final CollectionReference[] colRef = {db.collection("university")};
    colRef[0].get().addOnCompleteListener((OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>) task -> {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            listUni.clear();
            for(DocumentSnapshot a : task.getResult()){
                University u = new University();
                u.setID(a.getId());
                u.setDesc(a.get("Desc").toString());
                listUni.add(u);
            }
        }
    });
    ArrayAdapter<University> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>
            (getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                    listUni);
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout
            .simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner_search_UniFac.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
    return view;
}
public AddFacultyFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
}
```

Fragment three(the one that does update after I add something to firestore)

```
public class AddModuleFragment extends Fragment {
@BindView(R.id.spinner_search_UniMod)
Spinner spinner_search_UniMod;        
ArrayList<University> listUni = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Faculty> listFac = new ArrayList<>();
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_module,
            container,
            false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    final CollectionReference[] colRef = {db.collection("university")};
    colRef[0].get().addOnCompleteListener((OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>) task -> {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            listUni.clear();
            for(DocumentSnapshot a : task.getResult()){
                University u = new University();
                u.setID(a.getId());
                u.setDesc(a.get("Desc").toString());
                listUni.add(u);
            }
        }
    });
    ArrayAdapter<University> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>
            (getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                    listUni);
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout
            .simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner_search_UniMod.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
    return view;
}
public AddModuleFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
}
```

So just to clarify:

- All fragments are on a tabbed activity
- Fragment one adds information to Firestore
- Fragments two and three both have a spinner on them, populated the same way
- After adding information, only the spinner on fragment three updates with new value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when using view pager "taps". method `onCreateView` call just one time when the fragment creat. if you have more than 2 taps. when moving from one to three " taps not beside each other". method `onCreateView` recall

so the **solution** is:

overwrite `onResime` method in tap 2 and call the codes that should update the spinner.

```
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
     updateSpinner();

        super.onResume();
    }



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_module,
            container,
            false);

updateSpinner();
    return view;
}

private void updateSpinner(){
 ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    final CollectionReference[] colRef = {db.collection("university")};
    colRef[0].get().addOnCompleteListener((OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>) task -> {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            listUni.clear();
            for(DocumentSnapshot a : task.getResult()){
                University u = new University();
                u.setID(a.getId());
                u.setDesc(a.get("Desc").toString());
                listUni.add(u);
            }
        }
    });
    ArrayAdapter<University> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>
            (getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                    listUni);
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout
            .simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner_search_UniMod.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
    }
```